# Google Maps not showing route when building from latitude and longitude values

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using DirectionsService and DirectionsRenderer API to show route between stored geo data with waypoints. Everything works fine and I can see routes only if I take out specific set of geo-location from my array.

My geo data is : 

    `26.683661974268695, 75.23214340209961   //Dudu to
    26.723955272817047, 75.28688192367554   //Gidani to
    26.7450192, 75.32481949999999   //Palu Khurd to
    26.776571938799634, 75.37324905395508   //Mokhampura.`

If I take out 3rd row, then map show route with waypoint marker A B and C. But if I included 3rd row, then map isn't showing anything route. I am using `TravelMode.WALKING`.

I am not getting any error either. However if I manually input these geo points into http://maps.google.in page, it showing proper route.

Again just to clarify, I am having issue with specific geo-location values, not with implementation. I am able to see map route for other geo data set properly. There is just 1 location set which was causing blank map error and upon point by point tracing I narrowed down to this particular path set.

Any clue would be really helpful.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the coordinate 26.7450192, 75.32481949999999 in Geocoder tool

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D26.745019%252C75.324819

As you can see this point is far away from the road on the base map, although if you switch to satellite view you can clearly see the road close to this coordinate. At this point it looks like there is a missing road segment on the base map. This is a data issue.

For data related issues, you can use the ""Report a problem"" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to detect such case from javascript, that Google wasn't able to complete the route line at which point.

Comment: Also, if there is any alternative approach, I have a list of geo-location sets and my purpose is to plot them on a map in such way that it appear a path of travel with each marker being a stoppage. Easiest solution was using DirectionService with Waypoints. However in such case where it break due to no-road (like above) without any detection at programming end, it will defeat purpose. So any other way around?

Comment: You can try a Roads API that has a [Nearest Road](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest) functionality.  This way you can check if all points can be snapped to the road segment.